# How to disable Numpy asserts in a python script execution

Tags: python, numpy

I am running a Python script inside a Bash script. I use NumPy's `assert_allclose` and `assert` at multiple places. I would like to run this Python script by disabling all such instances without manually commenting them out.

Here is a simple example:

```bash
python run.py
```

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    assert False
    np.assert_allclose(1, 2)
```

I am aware of `-O` flag that can be added to `python run.py`. But this doesn't seem to disable the NumPy's assertion as `np.assert_allclose` uses `raise AssertionError(msg)` rather than `assert` itself.

Comment: write your own using python `assert` and `np.all_close` instead of raising `AssertionError`

Comment: You can't do that. The ```numpy.testing``` API is designed for unit testing. Why not create a wrapper around the numpy API?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, I don't think what you're looking for is built-in, but here's a wrapper you could use to do the job.

```py
import sys

def wrap_assertion(f, enabled=True):
    def assertion(*args, **kwargs):
        if assertion.enabled and "disable_assertions" not in sys.argv:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
    assertion.enabled = enabled
    return assertion
```

If you're running a script within an IDE, you could control whether the assertions are enabled like:

```
# Wrap np.testing.assert_allclose; disable by default
import numpy as np
assert_allclose = wrap_assertion(np.testing.assert_allclose, enabled=False)

# This does nothing
assert_allclose(1, 2)

# Enable the assertion
assert_allclose.enabled = True

# This raises an AssertionError
assert_allclose(2, 3)
# AssertionError:
# Not equal to tolerance rtol=1e-07, atol=0
# Mismatched elements: 1 / 1 (100%)
# Max absolute difference: 1
# Max relative difference: 0.33333333
#  x: array(2)
#  y: array(3)
```

Alternative, if you're running Python scripts from the command line, you can pass `'disable_assertions'` as a command line argument to override the choice specified in the program. For example, if the above code is in a script called `run.py`, then `python run.py` will result in the `AssertionError` shown as a comment, but `python run.py disable_assertions` will terminate without error.